# Divide the address range 192.168.64.0 /19 into 3 equally sized subnets.

Tags: ip, ip-address, subnet

Ok, so I know

```
0 bits gives you 1 subnet 
1 bit gives you 2 subnets 
2 bits gives you 4 subnets 
so on and so forth.
```

So in this case I need to borrow 2 bits as I need 3 subnets right? So now my new prefix length is /21 which is equal to, subnet mask: 255.255.248.0 and 2000 IP Addresses.

This is my answer for the following:

Subnet 1:

```
192.168.72.0/21

Network address = 192.168.64.0
1st host = 192.168.64.1
last host = 192.168.71.254
Broadcast = 192.168.61.255
```

Subnet 2:

```
192.168.72.0/21

Network address = 192.168.72.0
1st host = 192.168.72.1
last host = 192.168.80.254
Broadcast = 192.168.80.255
```

Subnet 2:

```
192.168.81.0/21

Network address = 192.168.81.0
1st host = 192.168.81.1
last host = 192.168.89.254
Broadcast = 192.168.89.255
```

Would you say I done it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Recheck your numbers. Lots of errors in them, even though the idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two major problems with your approach:

1. The number of addresses in a prefix is always a power of 2; you can't divide a prefix into 3 equal subnetworks.
2. CIDR notation specifies two parts, a base address and a prefix length *p*.  The network specified by `w.x.y.z/p` consists of the 2<sup>32-*p*</sup> addresses starting with `w.x.y.z`. Also, not just any base address can be used; it must be an address whose final 32-*p* bits are all zero.

---

Specifically,

> ```
> 192.168.72.0/21
>
> Network address = 192.168.64.0
> 1st host = 192.168.64.1
> last host = 192.168.71.254
> Broadcast = 192.168.61.255
> ```

This is wrong. 192.168.72.0/21 consists of the 2,048 addresses from 192.168.72.0 through 192.168.79.255. The other two are similarly wrong.

---

The closest you can get to splitting 192.168.64.0/19 into 3 equal parts would be something like

1. The first 2730 addresses, spread across

   ```
   192.168.64.0/21   (2048)
   192.168.72.0/23   ( 512)
   192.168.74.0/25   ( 128)
   192.168.74.128/27 (  32)
   192.168.74.160/29 (   8)
   192.168.74.168/31 (   2)
   ```
2. The next 2730 addresses, spread across

   ```
   192.168.74.170/31 (   2)
   192.168.74.172/30 (   4)
   192.168.74.176/28 (  16)
   192.168.74.192/26 (  64)
   192.168.75.0/24   ( 256)
   192.168.76.0/22   ( 512)
   192.168.80.0/22   ( 512)
   192.168.84.0/24   ( 256)
   192.168.85.0/26   (  64)
   192.168.85.64/28  (  16)
   192.168.85.80/30  (   4)
   ```

   (Take special note of the two /22s in this set. Even though they are consecutive, you cannot combine them into a single /21 because the network
   addresses of the two differ in the 21st bit.)
3. The last 2732 addresses, spread across

   ```
   192.168.85.84/30  (   4)
   192.168.85.88/29  (   8)
   192.168.85.96/27  (  32)
   192.168.85.128/25 ( 128)
   192.168.86.0/23   ( 512)
   192.168.88.0/21   (2048)
   ```

You could argue that groups of 2731, 2731, 2730 are more equal, but an odd number of addresses in a group makes the subnet breakdown even worse.

Comment: Its a practice exam question which is making me go crazy as it doesnt look realistic to me. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: @Chepner, aren't you splitting the address into 3 networks, with equal addresses instead of subnets? Imo the only correct way would be to create 4 /21 subnets.

Comment: Well, yes and yes :) If you want to split up a network, you can either split it into 3 (nearly) equal groups of continuous addresses, *or* you can split it into 2 or 4 subnetworks.